# HTML small font size for Middle-East and Eastern languages

Tags: html, css

I had a post on this related only to Middle East languages (and to which I didn't get a usable solution for me), but it turns out that the same problem appears when switching to any non-western language.

My Web application is supposed to support all languages with all character sets. From all aspects (database, direction, etc.) it works fine, except that the size of the characters when selecting for instance, Arabic, Japanese, Hebrew, etc., is significantly smaller than that of English.

I understand that there is a way to scale fonts globally, but don't know exactly how to do it.

My application is developed in HTML, JavaScript and AngularJS.

Comment: This is probably due to the fonts you do use.

Comment: And...? I have a global definition: `<font face="verdana">`. What should this be changed to?

Comment: `<span style="font-face:verdana">`

Comment: Sorry @redolent but I don't quite understand your comment, no what I should do with it.

Comment: What font size units are you using? Absolute or relative ones?

Comment: @FDavidov You asked what tag it should be replaced with?

Comment: @FDavidov, Verdana doesn't incorporate all the glyphs needed for all languages, if you don't set explicitly a font which supports these glyphs, it will default to the ones available on your systems, which may not have the same default character size as Verdana.

Comment: It might be easier to simply resize the whole font, FontSquirrel offers such a [**tool**](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

Comment: @AlexG, but if OP doesn't provide the fonts, he can't know which one his end-users will use.

Comment: try to change the font you are using, it might be the reason

Comment: FDavidov: I've noticed that after I edit your posts, you tend to roll back once to an earlier version, and then roll back again to mine. This seems to be harmless, but I am curious why you do it. Are you just looking to remove other folks' edit attribution from the question?

Comment: @halfer, I had a long discussion with other reviewer in the past in relation to certain type of editing that disregard the **culture** of people for different origins. I don't quite recall your editing and hence this response is with the due reservations (about its applicability). It is in my genes to **thank in advance**, to use upper case in abbreviations, etc., and not to follow trends just because other people do (history has plenty of very bad examples on that). Moreover, my original question is close to 3 years old, and viewed 200 times only, so no point in spending time on it. Cheers.

Comment: @FDavidov: thanks for your thoughts. There are probably two broad points to make. Firstly, Stack Overflow Q&A are like documentation or Wikipedia. I appreciate this comes as a surprise to some folks, but the most committed users on the platform see it that way, particularly including diamond moderators. We are in favour of the kind of technical writing that one gets in manuals - and in much of the Help Centre material, there is a "cut through the fluff, get your answers quickly" mentality. That approach has pervaded Stack Overflow pretty much since its inception.

Comment: Secondly, within the editing culture I have described, there is no process by which chatty material could get a pass based on its author. That would be enormously difficult in practice, since we'd need to liaise with each author to determine their personal preferences before editing, and that runs counter to the licenses conditions everyone agrees to in order to post here. One of the main Help Centre documents says "if you do not like your posts being edited, this site may not be for you". It is right there, as it were, in the _genes_ of the system.

Comment: We have from time to time had people insist on signatures, religious salutations, lengthy explanations of their career progress to date, copy+paste boilerplate and business URLs, all-lower-case material sent from a mobile phone, etc., and undoubtedly those folks all felt their material was justified based on the supremacy of authorship. But broadly we do not do that here. References: [fluff removal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions), [collaborative editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

Comment: If you would like to argue for a change in direction in editing, then you may make a policy proposal change to Meta. It was hinted in a blog post from Stack Overflow Inc last year that some parts of the employee team would be willing to look at that. However, it may have to be balanced against a potential loss of volunteer moderators/editors who would walk away based on the perception that material quality would go the same way as Quora, Yahoo Questions and Experts Exchange.

Comment: (I still don't quite understand the double rollback, but it is only to satisfy my curiosity, and I don't want to derail the above justification for editing, which is much more important).

Comment: @halfer, just to make one tiny point here, the double-rollback comes from my lack if understanding on how to "reject changes and o back to the original". Now, I would have no reservations in many cases except that sometimes, the only change made to a post would be from "HTML" to "html", or deleting part of a title like "HTML - How can I..." being changed to "How can I ...". So, my expectation would not be to have a complete review of policy, but to have some flexibility. Last, please don't think I do not appreciate this site or the work you do. Quite the contrary in fact. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. Yes, the "detagging" of titles is deliberate, mainly because the tag system automatically tags page titles anyway. I wrote the [canonical answer on title formulation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076). While that is not set in stone (and could be modified by a future policy change), it seems to be what _Meta_ is in favour of now.

Comment: @halfer, using your example (link), many times my posts were edited from _How do I do that in HTML?_ to _How do I do that in html?_, meaning, **HTML** in lower case. This type of changes is what I meant and is quite annoying to be frank (why would people spend time on this and force me to do the same addressing the change?).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yes, that change would be wrong, in my view; acronyms should be in all-caps as per long-standing conventions for English. If you see an editor getting things persistently wrong (on anyone's posts) then feel free to flag a post and explain your concerns to a diamond moderator. They may take an action based on their own judgement, such as having a private chat with that editor, or in persistent/severe cases, applying a temporary timeout to that editor.

Comment: (And, of course, you can always comment to an editor to discuss particular edits).

Comment: @halfer, will do. Thanks you for your time and keep your good work. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

We have some experiences of developing CSS styles per language. Here is the table we use for proper font sizes.
Primary use for these font sizes are desktop (web) applications. For mobile applications, some adjustment may be needed but they are likely scaled based on these sizes.

- Arabic: 11 - 14px
- Bengali: 13 - 16px
- Cyrillic (Russian, Bulgarian,
  Ukranian, etc.): 9 - 12px
- Greek: 9 - 12px
- Hebrew: 9 - 12px
- Hindi: 11 - 14px
- Latin (English, French, German, Italian, Spanish, etc.): 9 - 12px
- Malayalam: 11- 14px
- Japanese: 11 - 14px
- Korean: 9 - 12px
- Simplified Chinese: 11 - 14px
- Traditional Chinese: 11 - 14px
- Telugu: 11 - 14px
- Thai: 11 - 14px

Answer (score 0):

You can specify foreign fonts. You may have to download a font for that language, but all you have to is "stack" it with English fonts. Let me clarify with this CSS example:

```
p {
    font-family: 'AsciiSans'
               , '游ゴシック体'
               , 'Yu Gothic'
               , YuGothic
               , Meiryo
               , 'Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro'
               , sans-serif
}
```

So you can see that they're using this method here. `AsciiSans` doesn't have Japanese characters, so the browser will use the next font.

EDIT

The reason this is important; find a font for each language that is the same size as your english font. Or find a smaller english font. There are plenty of free fonts. Hopefully there's just an international one you can use (Maybe "OpenSans")

e.x.:

http://www.fontspace.com/category/arabic

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans

EDIT 2

To include Open Sans, add the following:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
```

and do either `<font face="Open Sans">my text</font>`

or `<span style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;">my text</span>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but(like your comment above), I don't quite understand how can I solve my problem (my fault, not yours). Could you expand a little bit this and provide instructions on how to do it (please consider that I don't have much experience with this; it is my very first application!). Thanks.

Comment: Edited. Can you see if my explanation is clear enough? :)

Comment: Have you tried a font like Open Sans? They may size the characters more evenly.

Comment: Actually I did @redolent (tried `<font face="OpenSans">`), but it looks that the font is not the right one (though with this English, Arabic and Hebrew do appear the same size; I didn't check others). I would use this except that the received font is quite ugly. Am I defining it wrongly? Do I need to download this font? If yes, how?

Comment: OK, please read my 2nd edit above. I got my material from https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open+Sans

Comment: Many thanks @redolent. I did get the font correctly (which is quite nice indeed for western languages), but still size of Arabic and Hebrew is significantly smaller (and, by the way, does not appear to be from the same family).

Comment: @FDavidov, an redolent, OpenSans is just a western language font, if you need to include other languages, have a look to [Noto fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) (by the same Google). You'll still have to load different font families for different languages, which may become a **big** loading for all languages, so it's better to load only the required one.

Comment: @Kaiido is right. If you can just *try* one of the Arabic fonts, maybe it will show you an option that may work.

Comment: @Kaiido, I just checked the link and it is great!!! What I may try is to load only the required fonts which will be the one selected by the user for the interface (which is one of a rather reduced list of, say, 10 languages) plus those that the user selected in his profile (say, up to 5 which may also overlap with those if the interface). So, in the worst case I would need 15 languages. Will check how I can select specific languages for download by the client-side code. Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you must have a `lang` attribute appended to `html` tag. You can style on the base of that attribute like this.

```
body { font-family: "Verdana"; font-size: 12px;} /** global **/
*[lang="ar"] {font-family: "Scheherazade",serif; font-size: 16px !important;} /** for arabic **/
```

This might not be a perfect solution as you can't append lang attribute to every DOM element since you can have different font sizes for different elments. But you can tweak this solution as you need.

I solved this problem in one of my applications using this technique. But with `SASS` or `LESS`, its much easier to handle all this. Since you are using AngularJS, so you can also define language based classes and then assign to specific DOM elements using a directive.

Comment: Good answer. Apparently it's supported in plenty of browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Thank you @Bilal for your answer. You are right, I have this: `<html lang="en-us" ng-app="MyApp">`. As per your suggestion, I don't quite see how I can do it since I'm using quite many font sizes all across the application, and changing things everywhere would be madness. It was my impression that you could say something like "for Arabic expand fonts to 130%; for Japanese expand font 140%;...". That would allow me to make the change in one location (index.html) and would apply all over the application (SPA).

Comment: Yep exactly. Thats why I said that you can tweak as per your requirement. :)